# iPhone xCode quit multitask applications

Tags: xcode

is it possible from my new app to quit all 'other' apps that are running in multitask mode. I've got about 30 and can't be bothered quiting each one. Or do I not have access to other multitask modes from my application.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: You don't have control over other applications, for good reason. There is no possible scenario where it would be a good idea for your application kill another application. Can you imagine how pissed off anyone'd be if he installed an app that quit other apps?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no chance to kill other applications.

Answer (score 0):

One app cannot force others to quit. Furthermore, there should be no need to do so.

If memory becomes constrained, the OS will issue escalating low memory warnings to everyone requesting that they free memory. If they refuse or are unable to do so then they'll be terminated. The front running app will be the last to be terminated.